# GWT - CssResource - common style - good practice

Tags: gwt

I have 5 views(.ui.xml). On every view i paste soemthing like that:

```
<ui:style src="../MyStyle.css" />
```

and on every button on every page I put styleName attribute:

```
<g:Button ui:field="buttonName" styleName="{style.myButtonStyle}" />
```

My Question is: Do I have to put styleName for all my buttons ? I would like to do something general style for this kind of widget .
What is good practice for this case?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to customize [GWT themes](http://code.google.com/intl/ru/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiCss.html#themes) or create your own ? I think this is what you need to do.

Answer (score 0):

Create your own button MyButton by extending Composite and define the UIBinder for this Button with style once.

Next you can re-use this button by adding your own namespace in the views.

Here's your widget :

```
package com.example.widgets;
...
public class MyButton extends Composite {

    interface MyButtonUiBinder extends UiBinder<Widget, MyButton> {
    }

    private static MyButtonUiBinder uiBinder = GWT.create(MyButtonUiBinder.class);

    @UiField
    Button wrapped;

    public MyButton() {
        initWidget(uiBinder.createAndBindUi(this));
    }

}
```

and the UIBinder file :

```
<ui:UiBinder xmlns:ui='urn:ui:com.google.gwt.uibinder'
    xmlns:g='urn:import:com.google.gwt.user.client.ui'>

    <ui:style>
        .myStyle {
            text-shadow: gray;
            color: gray;
            font-size: 12px;
            text-decoration: italic;    
        }
    </ui:style>

    <g:HTMLPanel>
            <g:Button ui:field="wrapped" styleName="{style.myStyle}" />
    </g:HTMLPanel>
</ui:UiBinder>
```

In your views, you can now include this button in the UIBinder files :

```
<!DOCTYPE ui:UiBinder SYSTEM "http://dl.google.com/gwt/DTD/xhtml.ent">
<ui:UiBinder xmlns:ui="urn:ui:com.google.gwt.uibinder"
    xmlns:g='urn:import:com.google.gwt.user.client.ui' xmlns:k='urn:import:com.example.widgets'>

 <g:AbsolutePanel width="350px" height="225px">
        <g:at left='10' top='0'> 

                 <k:MyButton></k:MyButton>
</g:at>
</g:AbsolutePanel>

</ui:UiBinder>
```

If you need to set the text or other properties on your personal widget, simply delegate the methods from the wrapped button to expose them.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to use `addStyleDependentName()` which would create an additional style by appending that to the primary style name, and allow you to apply specific styling.

For example, `.gwt-Button` is the default primary style for `Button`. If you have a set of 5 (N) buttons you like to style in the same way, you'd instantiate them with , which would add an additional style for this button: `.gwt-Button-customButton`, which you can add to a .css file and include in the module once.